# Ractive.js app, how to keep scroll position when pressing the back/forward buttons in the browser?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, ractivejs

I currently work on a project using Ractive. The project is a single-page app that has implemented routing as suggested by this project: [notetaker-ractive](https://github.com/PaquitoSoft/notetaker-ractive). The tutorial it belongs to is [here](http://paquitosoftware.com/create-a-ractive-application-tutorial/).

*What I haven’t been able to figure out is a good strategy for handling scrolling when pressing the back/forward buttons.* I'd like to keep the scroll position in e.g. search results when the user navigates.

I have searched and read about the browsers handling this stuff differently and also that the involved APIs make restoring scroll brittle. I come from React development and react-router tries to handle this there, but I don't know of any solution that is more generic.What would be the recommended library / technique to get this all working (as best as possible by today’s standards) with Ractive?

One thing I have picked up already is that the data should be cached to load synchronously when navigating.

Thanks in advance for any insights!